# What exactly is the difference between train() and predict() and when to use either?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, training-data

I am learning a bit of logistic regression and trying to understand the difference between `train()` and `predict()`. Say for example, I have a data set on which I am performing logistic regression...

1. I split 50-50 into a training and test set.
2. I use the glm on the training set.
3. I use predict:

   ```
   pred1 <- predict(glm1, newdata=testset, type="response")
   ```
4. I set a cutoff and split the results:

   ```
   pred1 <-  ifelse(fitted.values(glm1) >= cutoff, 1, 0)
   ```
5. I can view a confusion matrix:

   ```
   confusionMatrix(pred1, Classifier)
   ```

Where does `train()` come into play? Would it only come into play if I was using a K-fold cross-validation scheme? Most of what I have seen online uses predict. However, I keep seeing `train()` on various posts/blogs, and where I see `train()`, I don't see `predict()`.

Any insight would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I presume you are talking about the **caret** package here? If not, where does `train()` come from?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the `train` function from the [caret package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html). It's a function written in a package that helps make certain tasks easier. You should probably read the documentation and [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf) for that package if you want to learn more about the functions it provides. `predict()` is a base generic method to get fitted values from models. It's hard to compare them.

Comment: GavinSimpson, @MrFlick: Yes, its from the caret package.  Just read through the documentation; understood that it is for evaluation, choosing optimal model, estimating performance.  I guess I felt like I had to be using it. Thanks guys.